# Where to find .Net ORMs comparison with numbers or charts?

Tags: .net, database, ado.net

Where to find .Net ORMs comparison with numbers or charts?

I am building a new websites, will work on arranging images and manipulate images online, so it will contain a lot of images, and sure many images make the website pages load slower.

So the speed of the data access layer very important for me, and i am searching for an ORM because i want to decrease the development time.

If you know any website or blog post contain a good comparison, please tell us.

**Update**:

I know there are a lot of questions on SO about ORM, but all recommend one, or tell about one that its better than another, i don't want you to recommend one, i just want to see a comparison and every one later can decide based on his needs

Comment: all comparisons are going to be subjective, and depend on your business needs.

Comment: So you want someone to do all the research for you to build a competitive matrix showing strengths / weakness / pro / con / features/ etc?  Lets see, that should only take about 40-50 hours to complete...

Comment: No, i am asking if exist, don't want anyone to do this for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check ormbattle.net. not very complete, but can giveo some idea

Comment: ORMBattle.net has been frequently and correctly cited as a vendor-created website and is often labelled as a biased comparison.  Just sayin'.

Answer (score 2):

Please see these previously asked SO questions:

- [Which ORM for .net would you recommend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132676/which-orm-for-net-would-you-recommend)
- [Easiest to learn and use .NET ORM framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557948/easiest-to-learn-and-use-net-orm-framework)
- [Best Performing ORM for .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146087/best-performing-orm-for-net)
- [Best free ORM tools to use with .NET 2.0/3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206197/best-free-orm-tools-to-use-with-net-2-0-3-5/206284)
- [ORM and SOA in the .NET world](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412660/orm-and-soa-in-the-net-world)
- [Some suggestions on which .NET ORM to look at learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550929/some-suggestions-on-which-net-orm-to-look-at-learning)

Comment: I know all of these question and saw them all before, but always the answer about recommendations, and based on personal experience, i don't want some one to tell me to use this ORM, i want to see a comparison and i will decide my self based on my needs, because in fact each ORm has its Advantages/Disadvantages.